# Stopping JMSJobQueueBundle Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, queue, jms

I am using the JMSJobQueueBundle and this is working fine. But now i want to stop queue'ing after all pending request are done.

Now I am giving a max-runtime argument with the command but is it possible to stop queue'ing after all pending options are done.

Maybe manually stop the queue?

Answer (score 1):

To stop the queue'ing from running i used the process component from Symfony:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Then I checked the output from the requests with the function `getOutput()`. If this was empty I call the function `stop()` from the `Process` class.